# what is role of parameter "theme" of ResourcesCompat.getDrawable in android studio?

Tags: android, themes

I'm android studio beginner. I found ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(Resources res, int id, Resources.Theme theme) method while learning android studio by book. but there was no expression there. so I surfed the internet to know about the method. I found role of 2 parameter. but I don't know the parameter "theme" yet. what is role of parameter "theme"?

Comment: the theme is a new version of Style it supports day/night mode Like new `Dark mode` option in android

Comment: can you express in more detail?

Comment: what is day/night mode? and if it's dark mode, is it like instagram's dark mode?

Comment: you can now check how the application view in dark mode, you design your application according to the theme `DarkMode`